# Using a base guard for all routes in Angular 2 application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-guards

Is there a way to set a "base" `canActivate` when configuring routes in Angular2? So that all routes are covered by the same base check, and then each route can have a more granular check.

I have an `AppModule` with routing like this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: '',
                component: HomeComponent,
                canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService],
                data: { roles: [Roles.User] }
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And for the feature module `FeatureModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: "feature",
                component: FeatureComponent,

                // I'd like to avoid having to do this:
                canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService],
                data: { roles: [Roles.User] }
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class FeatureRoutingModule { }
```

I let `AuthenticationGuardService` check if a user has access to a route by using the roles provided in `data`.

Can I do something to avoid having to set `canActivate` and `data` in all my feature routing modules? I'd like to just configure a "base" `canActivate` for all routes in this application.

Comment: You can create route object from a class or helper function. That's the most simple (and probably the only available) solution.

Comment: @estus So you mean that I should do something like: `RouterModule.forChild([helperService.getRoute("feature", FeatureComponent)])`? And then that helper service (or class or method..) always adds the base Guard to the generated route object?

Comment: Yes. I would personally go with something like `RouterModule.forChild([new AuthenticatedRoute({ path: ..., component: ... })])`

Comment: @Joel, what was the verdict? do you mind sharing your AuthenticationGuardService? on further googling, this sounds like a solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672453/angular2-restrict-all-routes

Comment: @sawe Haven't really found a solution I'm happy with. The one you link to is ok, but still requires you to put it in all your routing modules.

Comment: i meant, you could have your main route  with 
{path: '', canActivate: [AuthenticationGuardService], canActivateChild: [AuthenticationChildGuardService], children: [... /*no need for auth guard here, this is where you would add all your other routes as children on the main component-less route*/]}
you still need the `data` though

Comment: on closer inspection, if you have more than 2 levels of hierarchy, my suggestion might/will not work

Answer (score 12):

I've written a solution to add the Guard dynamically for every routes of my app (including those defined by child modules).

I've figured out this solution while reading [this Router Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#inspect-the-routers-configuration).

**Edit**

Here is a living [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-guards-sample) sample.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: { skipGuard: true } },
  { path: '403', component: ForbiddenComponent, data: { skipGuard: true } },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent, data: { skipGuard: true } }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  
  constructor(router: Router) {
    router.config
        .filter(route => !route.data || !route.data.skipGuard)
        .forEach(route => this.addGuard(route));
  }
  
  private addGuard(route: Route): void {
    route.canActivate = route.canActivate ? 
                   [AuthGuard].concat(route.canActivate) : [AuthGuard];
    route.canActivateChild = route.canActivate ? 
                   [AuthGuard].concat(route.canActivate) : [AuthGuard];
  }
}
```

Comment: just a quick note that if `route.canActivate` is undefined for a non skipped route, then the updated `route.canActivate` will produce `[AuthGuard, undefined]` using above answer. And its actually very hard to debug and be found as the actual reason for the resulting error.

Comment: I tried to implement this but I couldn't. The guard is added but I get an error on every navigation. Maybe it's because my guard has dependencies that are resolved differently when injected in `AppRoutingModule`. Do you have a running example on stackblitz or something like that? Thanks.

Comment: @MarcosDimitrio I've just edited the answer to include a StackBlitz demo.

Comment: @ar27111994  I've made a fix to the error you have pointed. Check it in the stackblitz link I've included.

Answer (score 9):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'builds', component: BuildsComponent },
      { path: 'files', component: FilesComponent },
      { path: 'publications', component: PublicationsComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Comment: While working, this is currently not safe because child routes added via `forChild` are added as siblings to the `forRoot` routes thus not within the hierarchy and will not trigger the guard.

Comment: You should use `canActivateChild` instead of `canActivate` for this to work properly.