# Angular2 restrict all routes

Tags: angular

Helloo,

I have created a guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { 
    }

    canActivate() {

        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

and have multiple modules with multiple routes inside them. How do I easily restrict every route in my app  with this guard?

Best regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setup an empty route with guard, and make the rest of your routes `children` of that one:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [...restOfYourRoutes] }])
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use componentless routes

```
{ path: '', canActivate: [MyGuard], children: [
   {path: 'x1', ...},
   {path: 'x2', ...},
```

`MyGuard` will be applied to all child routes.